# Framing VideoOutput item in Qt QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5.12

I am using a VideoOutput item, which I have placed inside a Rectangle. This VideoOutput goes on top of the Rectangle, of its border and its rounded corners.

```
  Rectangle{
    radius: 12
    width: 200
    height: width
    border.color: black
    border.width: 15

    VideoOutput {
      fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
      anchors.fill: parent
      source: myCamera
      autoOrientation: true
    }
  }

  Camera {
    id: myCamera
    focus {
      focusMode: CameraFocus.FocusContinuous
      focusPointMode: CameraFocus.FocusPointAuto
    }
    captureMode: Camera.CaptureViewfinder
  }
```

I intentionaly made the border thick so it really shows what is going on. The border is hidden by the VideoOutput, and the rounded corners are ignored.

I can imagine that the VideoOutput item would use some acceleration tricks, so it might not play well with standard QML item behaviour. But is there a way get this to work, without adding a filter element, or is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Set transparent Rectangle z-index or place it over the video output and border will be visible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this doesn't really fix the issue: the rectangle is indeed visible, but the video's corners are not trimmed based on the rectangle's radius.
I could effectively add a drawing on top of my video to recreate a frame with rounded corners if all I wanted was a frame around my video, but in my case I'm trying to make the background behind the video to become visible (including in the rounder corners...)

Comment: There is another option to put mask on videooutput

Comment: This would be using things like ThresholdMask and OpacityMask, or are there items better suited for this?